# Migrate UITableView's and UICollectionView's Xib in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, hstack, vstack

I have converted my existing `Xib` `UI` in `SwiftUI`.

Is it possible to use `SwiftUI` in existing `UITableView` and `UICollectionView`?

Here is the code i have done in `SwiftUI`

```
struct LandmarkList: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var userData: UserData

    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
            Text("Pinkesh Gjr")
                .font(.title)
            HStack(alignment: .top) {
                Text("iOS Developer")
                    .font(.subheadline)
                Spacer()
                Text("California")
                    .font(.subheadline)
            }
        }
    }
}
```